# Can I share .as file bettween two applications in same project in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I have two applications in my project 'test' the applications are one.mxml and two.mxml and i want to use the same main.as file in both using

```
    <script source='main.as'/>
```

Can I access the components of both applications from main.as when both are running simultaniously.

Thanks in Advance

Prashant Dubey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you compile your projects? Which version of Flex/Flash Builder are you using? Also to note, script files are shared at compile time, not runtime.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I also searched and got that it is not possible.Actually i was running the main mxml file and on an event in that i am loading the second in the same browser window using iframe.
I wanted to have a single .as file included in both but that is not possible so i did with separate .as file.

Thanks 4 reply
Prashant